# cout stream goes bad

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I was just trying this sample C++11 code and realised that cout stream goes bad and I have to explicitly clear the bad/fail bit, for the last cout statement to be printed.

Has anyone here experienced it?? or am I missing something??

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int8_t* c{};
    cerr << boolalpha << (!cout) << endl;
    cout << c << endl;
    cerr << boolalpha << (!cout) << endl;

    //cout.clear(); //Why does cout go bad??

    int16_t arr[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << "arr size: " << sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How* would `std::cout` go bad? Also, you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, as you try to print a `nullptr` string. Yes, on system where `int8_t` is based on `char` (which is just about all systems today) then the output operator `<<` thinks that you try to print a string.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I understand what you mean.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Actually, if `int8_t` exists (it doesn't on all systems), it _must_ be a typedef to `signed char` (or maybe `char`).  Only character types are allowed to have 8 bits.

Comment: @JamesKanze Even on systems where `char` is not 8 bits?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg On systems where `char` is not 8 bits, `int8_t` won't be defined.  The standard requires it to be defined as a typedef to a signed integral type of exactly 8 bits.  The standard also requires that the character types be the smallest integral types, and they are the only integral types which can have less than 16 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int8_t* c{};
```

Here you've initialized `c` to `nullptr`.

Most likely `int8_t` is a typdef for `(signed) char` on your platform. In that case, you have undefined behavior in your example because you're violating the requirements of the `operator<<` overload that takes a `(signed) char const *`, which requires that the pointer not be null.

From *§27.7.3.6.4/3 [ostream.inserters.character]*

> *Requires:* s shall not be a null pointer.

Comment: `int8_t`, if it exists, _must_ be a typedef to `signed char` (or possibly plain `char`, if there is no possibility of plain `char` being unsigned).  There's really no reason to use it, unless you want your compilation to fail on some systems.